# Not able to see Conda environments

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, data-science, anaconda3

I can't see environments in my Conda as in this picture. I used Anaconda Prompt and type `conda info --envs` and shows this error message

```
>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> ERROR REPORT <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Acer\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\exceptions.py", line 1082, in __call__
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Acer\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\main.py", line 87, in _main
    exit_code = do_call(args, p)
  File "C:\Users\Acer\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\conda_argparse.py", line 84, in do_call
    return getattr(module, func_name)(args, parser)
  File "C:\Users\Acer\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\main_info.py", line 317, in execute
    info_dict = get_info_dict(args.system)
  File "C:\Users\Acer\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\main_info.py", line 163, in get_info_dict
    pkgs_dirs=context.pkgs_dirs,
  File "C:\Users\Acer\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\base\context.py", line 530, in pkgs_dirs
    fixed_dirs += user_data_dir(APP_NAME, APP_NAME),
  File "C:\Users\Acer\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\_vendor\appdirs.py", line 67, in user_data_dir
    path = os.path.join(_get_win_folder(const), appauthor, appname)
  File "C:\Users\Acer\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\_vendor\appdirs.py", line 284, in _get_win_folder_with_pywin32
    from win32com.shell import shellcon, shell
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing shell: The specified procedure could not be found.
```

Can someone help me and know the reason this happening? [Screenshot of trouble](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fCJ1O.jpg)

Comment: Please post as text not an image.

Comment: Please read [ask], especially the part about posting images of code

Comment: I am sorry, I didn't know that. I am just edited as you said.